# Accu-Chek Glucose Meter disconnects automatically

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Accu-Gluco Meter to connect with my Raspberry-Pi4.
I am using bluetoothctl & also installed pygatt library.
I could pair and connect using bluetoothctl commands and everything was working fine initially.
But now the meter get's paired and connected but disconnects within one second.
Following are the commands and responses

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect 11:22:33:44:55:66
Attempting to connect 11:22:33:44:55:66
[CHG] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 Connected: no
```

I guess there is no problem with the Accu-Chek meter because it works perfectly fine with the mobile app like nrfConnect.

Comment: IMHO:  You should be prepared to invest lots of **your time** if you plan on using the RPi BT to connect anything. Again - IMHO - RPi BT sux.